# webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest works in one program but can't get it to work in another

Tags: ios

I've using `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` very successfully in one of my programs, but the whole project was a proof of concept and scruffy and I'm starting afresh with a new project.

However `shouldStartLoadWithReqest` is no longer being invoked for me but I can't see where the important difference between the two projects is (however one difference is the first is using .nibs, in the 2nd I'm not using them).

To get things started I'm using a controller with the UIWebView as its view:

```
@interface IMSRootController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate> {

    UIWebView*  webView;
}
```

(webView is declared as a @property and @synthesized)

```
- (void)loadView {
    [super loadView];
    webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
    self.view = webView;
    [webView release]; }


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
    [self displayPage]; }

-(void) displayPage { ...   [webView loadHTMLString:self.htmlString baseURL:baseURL]; }


- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType 
{
...
```

What's wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your object is not being set as a delegate of the `UIWebView` object, hence you will not receive any delegate messages. At some point, either in `loadView` or even `displayPage` (but before the call to `loadHTMLString:baseURL:`), do:

```
webView.delegate = self;
```

Comment: I have a similar problem, I have set the delegate and the methods webViewDidFinishLoad and webViewDidStartLoad are being called but shouldStartLoadWithRequest doesn't get called when I click on a link??

Comment: If you are getting `webViewDidStartLoad` and `webViewDidFinishLoad` called, then you **should** also get `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` called as well. Double check that your delegate method implementation is correctly defined (`- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType`)

Comment: that was the problem, my method was incorrectly defined despite copying from the definition. I hadn't thought it might be something so simple. Cheers

Comment: Excellent! Glad to hear it was as simple as that.